# MongoDB - Update the array's sub-document to include the calculated value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Basically, I want to subtract two fields from each sub-object in an array field of an input document and then update the document to include the calculated value.

For example,

```
{   
    "title" : "The Hobbit",

    "rating_average" : "???",
    "ratings" : [
        {
            "title" : "best book ever",
            "start" : 5,
            "finish" : 7
        },
        {
            "title" : "good book",
            "start" : 4,
            "finish" : 8
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to subtract finish-start for each object and **then save that new calculated field into my existing documents.**

So after updating my documents it should look like:

```
{   
    "title" : "The Hobbit",
    "rating_average" : "???",
    "ratings" : [
        {
            "title" : "best book ever",
            "start" : 5,
            "finish" : 7
             “diff”:2
        },
        {
            "title" : "good book",
            "start" : 4,
            "finish" : 8
             “diff”:4

        }
    ]
}
```

So, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your mongoDB version ?

Comment: @srinivasy, version 4.2

Answer (score 3):

Here is the the *version 4.2* update method which supports aggregation pipeline stage [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/index.html). The `$map` projection operator is used to derive the `diff` field for each of the array elements:

```
db.test.updateOne(
   {  },
   [
       {
         $set: {
             ratings: {
                 $map: {
                     input: "$ratings",
                        as: "rating",
                        in: {
                             $mergeObjects: [
                                 "$$rating",
                                 { "diff" : { $subtract: [ "$$rating.finish", "$$rating.start" ] } }
                             ]
                        }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  ]
)
```

Comment: bloody beautiful... this should be the accepted answer :-)
i'm off to read up on the $map operator...

Answer (score 1):

the following aggregation pipeline will create a new collection with diff field in the array.

```java
db.books.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$ratings"
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "ratings.diff": {
                $subtract: ["$ratings.finish", "$ratings.start"]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            title: {
                $first: "$title"
            },
            rating_average: {
                $first: "$rating_average"
            },
            ratings: {
                $addToSet: "$ratings"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "modified-books"
    }
])
```

you can even replace the existing colleciton by specifying `$out: "books"` in the last stage.

this is not an ideal way to get this done but i don't think there's any other alternatives.

Comment: you need not to use this, this is very destructive !! I agree as you said it's correct, but for explanation for someone : It would replace the entire collection with aggregation result, which would not be a case when you're updating few docs or it would be messy if not tested properly, If you've to use it then write it to new collection,I would say unless you're pretty sure of what the result of aggregation is on every doc then do not use $out..

Comment: @srinivasy agreed